# Is it possible to point a Typedef function pointer to a class member?

Tags: function-pointers, typedef, class-method

I am working with an executable that includes a DLL. For my testcase, I combined the code into a single executable. I am working with Visual Studio 2008 and Boost 1.43. I've tried researching this, but haven't found any clear answer. Thanks for the help.

In my main.h:

```
#include <string>

//These are normally defined in a seperate DLL
typedef std::string Typedef_func(const std::string & title);
void Register_My_Typedef(Typedef_func*);
//-------------------------------------------

class myClass
{
public:
    std::string func_one(const std::string & title);

    Typedef_func _test;

    void run();
};
```

In my main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

std::string workingFunc(const std::string & title)
{
    return "";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myclass* example;
    example->run();

    Register_My_Typedef(&workingFunc);//This works.

    return 0;
}

void myClass::run()
{
    //I want to point a Typedef_func* in a DLL to call myclass::func_one
    Typedef_func* tf = boost::bind(&myClass::func_one, this, "test"); //This does not.

    Register_My_Typedef(tf);
}

std::string myClass::funcOne(const std::string & title)
{
    return "";
}

void Register_My_Typedef(Typedef_func* passedIn)
{
    //Points the pointer in the DLL to passedIn
}
```

The DLL logic works fine when Register_My_Typedef is called on a function not in a class, but is it possible to call it from within a class? When I try to compile this code it returns:

When I try and compile in Windows XP with VS2008 I get:

> Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'boost::_bi::bind_t' to 'Typedef_func (__cdecl *)' with
>   [
>       R=std::string,
>       F=boost::_mfi::mf1,
>       L=boost::_bi::list2,boost::_bi::value>
>   ]
>
> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is Typedef itself is class member for a static member function & behave differently to non-static however works best reading rather class function of user defined class main.